# How POST all selected checked ARRAY item in Axios Post in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios

I have to a checkbox which is checked and the item must Axios post to get the total amount of the checked item, the checked item I have saved in the checked array, but I don't know how to call the checked array and post the checked array in the Axios.

This is the checked box input that I used to save the data in a checked array using the e.target.value.

```html
<input
  className="border-2"
  type="checkbox"
  value={`${items.ProductID},${items.VariationID},${items.Count}`}
  defaultChecked={!!checked[items.VariationID]}
  onChange={(e) => {
    handleChange(
      e,
      items.ProductID,
      items.VariationID,
      items.Count
    );
  }}
/>
```

This is how I create the handlechange to save the checked array and post the checked array. in the post, it replaces the prev item with the current item, but it should have both items in the post, I don't know how to call the checked array and post the checked array AXIOS Post.

```js
const handleChange = async (e, itemId, vId, qty) => {
  let updatedList = [...checked];

  if (e.target.checked) {
    updatedList = [...checked, e.target.value];
  } else {
    updatedList.splice(checked.indexOf(e.target.value), 1);
  }
  setChecked(updatedList);
  if (checked) {
    await Axios.post("/user/OrderSummary", {
      Products: [
        {
          ProductID: itemId,
          VariationID: vId,
          Count: qty,
        },
      ],
      CouponCode: [],
    });
  }

  console.log(updatedList);
};
```

Comment: @Phil can you help me with this question?

Answer (score 0):

```
await Axios.post("/user/OrderSummary", {
      Products: [
        {
          ProductID: itemId,
          VariationID: vId,
          Count: qty,
        },
      ],
      CouponCode: [],
    })
    .then(response => response.data)
    .then(data => {
         // Data
    })
    .catch(error => {
         // Error
    })
```

Comment: Can you plz explain the code?

Comment: @lucky [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [axios post example](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example)